# Leaflet not registering touch events on static map?

Tags: leaflet, mobile

I am attempting to create a tool that will present users with a web map, which cannot be zoomed, panned, etc. Just a static map, dynamically presented, ie at a semi-random location for the purpose of testing various aspects of map design/legibility.

I want users to be able to trace a line on the map with their finger using a touchscreen interface. I've been using leaflet, and things were going fine while I was developing on my laptop (click -> mousemove -> click events to draw a line), but when I went to test the application on my tablet, (touchstart, touchmove, touchend events??) nothing seems to happen.

Is leaflet somehow disabling these events? I am trying to add them to the map in the same way I had added click events, with the [.on](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events-on) method of the map object. No errors show up, it's just that nothing happens.

The (hopefully) relevant part of my code is below.

```
$m = L.map('map',{
    'center': $mapCenter,
    'zoom': 17,
    'zoomControl': false,
    'attributionControl':false,
    'animate':true
});
// disable all map movement
$m.dragging.disable();
$m.touchZoom.disable();
$m.doubleClickZoom.disable();
$m.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
$m.keyboard.disable();
// use OSM tiles for testing
L.tileLayer($tilesource).addTo($m);
// create and then add A and B
L.marker($A,{icon:$Aicon}).addTo($m);
L.marker($B,{icon:$Bicon}).addTo($m);
// add event listeners for user interaction
$m.on('touchstart',trackCursor);
$m.on('touchend',closeTrack);
// monitor cursor position
$m.on('touchmove',function(e){$cursorLocation = e.latlng});
```

I am using leaflet 1.0.2 and the Firefox 50.1.0 on Android.

Comment: I suggest you include which browser you were using, and which Leaflet version. The new `PointerEvent` interface in some web browsers has proven to be tricky to debug.

Comment: I updated my question. Leaflet is version 1.0.2 and Firefox is version 50.1.0 on Android.